# I have Coalesce function in odi mapping but not working

Tags: sql, oracle, coalesce

HI I have a coalesce logic inside my mapping in odi for a column and the coalesce is below, however after running the interface, the column is still null and not zero. is my coalesce wrong?

`COALESCE(case when C_ORG_HIER_D_LABEL_NO_DUPS_V.ORG_HIER_ROW_WID is not null then C_ORG_HIER_D_LABEL_NO_DUPS_V.ORG_HIER_ROW_WID when WC_ORG_HIER_D.ROW_WID is not null then  WC_ORG_HIER_D.ROW_WID else 0 end,0)`

Comment: your coalesce doesn't make any sense, because the case should already do what you're trying to achive. i would simplify the statement to COALESCE(C_ORG_HIER_D_LABEL_NO_DUPS_V.ORG_HIER_ROW_WID, WC_ORG_HIER_D.ROW_WID, 0)

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you want is:

```
COALESCE(C_ORG_HIER_D_LABEL_NO_DUPS_V.ORG_HIER_ROW_WID,
         WC_ORG_HIER_D.ROW_WID,
         0)
```

The `COALESCE()` seems to do exactly what you want.  The `CASE` is unnecessary.